# Visual studio C++ cross platform development for raspberry pi how to reference custom header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

I am new to C++.

I am making a C++ program for the raspberry pi zero w. I use Visual Studio in a cross platform configuration.

I have written a small C++ program to interrogate an counter chip that’s counting pulses from a anemometer (wind sensor) this program is performing an endless loop and updating every loop a global int variable `wind`.

I have defined this global variable in a header file `wind.h` so I can use the wind variable in other programs.
So far it works fine. But now I want to test if I can use the wind variable in another program. The problem is that how to tell Visual studio where to find the `wind.h` header file?
(on the raspberry it is located in the folder: /home/pi/projects/wind )

I did add the location of the header file in the projects Property's pages –> VC++ Directories –> Include Directories property like this: /projects/wind/. witch is displayed as: /projects/wind/;$(Include Path)

I also changed the Linker -> Input -> Library Dependencies property the same way it now reads : /projects/wind/;%(LibraryDependencies)

I have added a line    `#include <wind.h>`   into my program code (witch get the red curly intelisence fault).

And when I try to build I get the error : Cannot open source file “`wind.h`” .`
What is going wrong??

Comment: To help providing correct answer describe your directory structure in which both projects and files are located, where is including and where are project files, otherwise, it is very hard to guess what should be done.

Comment: Hi My Home directory on the raspberry pi is /home/pi/. my wind program is  /home/pi/projects/wind/bin/ARM/Release/wind.out the header file is in /home/pi/projects/wind/wind.h But my standard header files are in /home/usr/include/

Comment: OK but where is your file which includes wind.h (contains `#include <wind.h>`)

Comment: the new file compiled file will come in /home/pi/projects/windtest/bin/ARM/Debug/ .  The CPP file is in /home/pi/projects windtest. This is how Microsoft VS thinks it should be (-:

Comment: I understand that you missed slash and the path to cpp file is /home/pi/projects/windtest/"yourcppfile".cpp

Comment: Try to put the following inlcude directive into cpp file: include "../wind/wind.h"

Comment: Unfortunatly it still is not working. I think I first need to understand a bit more how these project properties work. the problem is that Microsoft gives very little documentation. anyway thanks for your help! apriciate.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong path to your include file. First try to set absolute path (rooted). Then if this works convert it to relative path. Remember that your new program when located in different directory may need to first change directory to common root for both projects i.e `../../projects/wind` or `../wind` depending what is your projects directory structure. The same is true for linker directories, they are relative to your new project file.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. changing to `/home/pi/projects/wind` gives the same error.